# Storage and Deleting Apps. How. What is Syncing and is it necessary?

Tags: google-plus

I have a Sony Xperia and i can't delete apps or move then to my sd card cz I keep getting warnings about my internal storage. Some apps on my phone are not even using memory but they are still listed in apps. Driving me crazy. How do i delete empty and unwanted apps and how do i store apps and other daya to my sd card. Iv lost all my photos and videos from factory resetting and not backing up my data. Also id it necessary to sync everything. What does syncing do. PLEASE HELP. Gill in Dublin Ireland

Comment: Which Sony Xperia model do you own?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Sony Xperia and i can't delete apps or move then to my sd
>   card cz I keep getting warnings about my internal storage.

Can you show me the message? About moving app to SD card, if the device is running 4.4 then there are chances the OS won't allow you to install apps on external SD card. I'm not using any Xperia model so I'm skeptical. A device model could help.

> How do i delete empty and unwanted apps and how do i store apps and
>   other daya to my sd card.

Did you mean apps or folders? I suggest uninstall apps from Settings -> Apps and select from the **Downloaded** list there. If you meant the folders then you can delete them using the **Files** application.

> Iv lost all my photos and videos from factory resetting and not backing up my data.

Always pull out things first before factory resetting. And be warned that synchronizing may not back up all your data. Video, images and apps maybe left out unless you use some other specific apps for that.

> Also id it necessary to sync everything. What does syncing do.

Normally the sync will be managed through accounts. You can go to Settings -> Accounts section and select one of the accounts here. Tap on it and see the checked options. Checked means synced, unchecked means not synced. Simple as that.